# I don't want to serve contents from public directory of Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I've a `Larvel 5.1` project running absolutely fine. let's say it's hosted at `http://www.example.com`. When I go to this `address`, it's working aboslutely fine and there is no `public/` in URL which is required. Now the only problem is that if someone goes to `http://www.example.com/public/` explcitly, he sees homepage contents without any CSS and JS loaded which is totally not good for SEO as it'll count as duplicated site. I've tried searching over internet but everyone is answering how to remove `public/` from URL, but in my case it's already removed. I just don't want user to see contents inside `public/` if he goes there explicitly. Is there any way to achieve this? I'll post my `.htaccess` file too here. It got many code, for enabling cache, adding `www.` with domain. Please help me to resolve this problem. I'm totally stuck.
Here is my `.htaccess` file contents

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
    AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    # Add a far future Expires header for fonts
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
    </IfModule>
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stems from what I think is a lazy design decision, allowing all directories and files to be entry points. WordPress does the same thing. You could fix it like so:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond $0 =public [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]* index.php [L]
```

That should ignore the directory check for just `/public/` and leave other functionality unchanged.

Comment: Thank you @Walf. It worked like a charm. Helped me a lot.I guess I should study Apache doc more ;-)

Comment: Apache docs are brilliant but it really takes practice to apply the general concepts to specific problems.

Answer (score -1):

in root create .htaccess page with the following content.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That last rule is basically an infinite loop of prefixing, only stopped by `LimitInternalRecursion`.